# Youtube API search returns "c" error with Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, get, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using C++ with Qt and I am trying to find Youtube videos searched by a certain keyword using the Youtube API.I already have an API key.

My code is :

```
void Youtube::searchVideos(QString keyword)
{

        int maxResults = 5; //the maximum of search results we want shown

        QString youtubeurl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&q=" +
            keyword +
            "%203%27%203&key=" + QString(YOUTUBE_API_KEY) +
            "&videoEmbeddable=true" +
            "&maxResults=" + QString::number(maxResults);

        QEventLoop loop;

        QUrl url(youtubeurl);

        if (_netManager == NULL)
        {
            _netManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
            QObject::connect(_netManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(processReply(QNetworkReply *)));
        }

        QNetworkRequest request(url);

        _reply = _netManager->get(request);

}

void Youtube::processReply(QNetworkReply * pReply)
{
    QVariant statusCodeV = pReply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
    QVariant redirectionTargetUrl = pReply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);

    QJsonObject results;

    if (pReply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {

        QByteArray message = pReply->readAll();

        QString str = QString::fromUtf8(message.data(), message.size());
        int statusCode = pReply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();

        qDebug() << QVariant(statusCode).toString();

        QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(message);
        results = jsonResponse.object();
        qDebug() << "Youtube API works.";

    }

    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Error searching on Youtube : " << QString(pReply->error()).toUtf8();

    }
}
```

And the output is : Error searching on Youtube :  "c"

I also used the same link and GET method in Javascript and it works fine however I always get this error in C++.

Comment: And what is the contents of `keyword`? What is the full URL?

Comment: keyword is a string that represents what we're searching for on Youtube like "music" or "funny videos".
The full URL looks something like this : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&q=music%203%27%203&key=YOUR_API_KEY&videoEmbeddable=true&maxResults=5
I can't show the API key so that link won't work.

Comment: That query in `keyword` doesn't look URL-encoded. Perhaps if you try that?

Comment: Actually, the error of QNetWorkReply is an enum, [enum QNetworkReply::NetworkError](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#NetworkError-enum). So You should consider 'c' as 99 in ASCII and reading from documentation 99 is QNetworkReply::UnknownNetworkError which description is: an unknown network-related error was detected

Comment: @JTejedor lol, Qt's documentation is as informative as YouTube's.

Comment: @Just_a_guy If you manually try your own app-generated URL (with your API_KEY, etc), does it work? Are you sure the URL is being generated correctly?

Comment: @ray yes,I take the URL and put in a browser and it works.

Comment: @Just_a_guy I mean, if the app prints it to the screen/console and you copy-n-paste, that is. You're simply pasting it as shown, right? If it works when you use it, but not when the app uses it, are you sure you're following the docs on how to prepare and issue the network/URL request?

Comment: @ray, It is totally true. ;-)

Comment: Use `pReply->errorString()` to print the error message. You are converting an integer to a string!

Comment: @Felix Ok,I used errorString() and now I get : 
Error searching on Youtube :  "Error creating SSL context ()"

Comment: Ah, ssl errors... do you have openssl installed? If yes, which version of Qt and openssl are you using. Once I know I can give you an answer

Comment: I don't think I have openssl installed.And I use Qt 5.9.1.

Comment: Well, thats the problem. To access https, Qt needs openssl! You will have to install openssl `1.0.*` (not 1.1, it's not supported yet). If you are on windows (the only platform without openssl), you can get it here: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html (Check the step to copy to your windows folder)

Comment: @Felix I installed openssl 1.0.2 and it doesn't return an error anymore.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wrap the results of the "comment-debugging" up as a short, clean answer:

- To print an error, use `pReply->errorString()`, do not convert the error code (an integer) to a string
- The real error here was that `https` is used without openssl installed

Solution: Install openssl 1.0.* (1.1.* is not supported with Qt 5.9). For windows, it can be downloaded here: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html